# How to explain the behavior of a PNP transistor as a transimpedance amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, audio

[image]

Can anyone explain how Q3 behaves? I mean in a way that: If base of Q3 goes positive ... increases.. ect and if base of Q3 goes negative ... happens and so forth and so on. in that fashion.

I see this PNP in many audio amplifier circuits but hard to visualize its dynamic behavior.

Comment: Why do you restrict possible answers to a "behavior as a transimpedance amplifier"? More than that, the function of Q3 was discussed with you yesterday - extensively (Q2 in a similar circuit!).

Comment: i know but that way of explanations was beyond my level.

Comment: İ needed something like MikeP's answer to grasp the idea

Comment: To be able to understand why we sometimes call Q3 a transimpedance amplifier. You need to study what transimpedance amplifier is and how it work.

Comment: And in real world circuit Q3 also have a dominant pole capacitor. So the Q3 behaviors as a integrator, and a key property of an integrator is that it converts a current input into a voltage output (transimpeadance circuit).

Comment: @G36 in many basic texts it is not mentioned i mean the transimpedance amplifier as PNP. would be great if u can suggest me one.

Comment: The fact that it is a transimpedance amplifier has nothing to do with the fact that it is PNP.

Comment: ok but im asking the PNP case do u know a text that explains that in a similar circuit?

Comment: Did you ever try to design a DC (direct) coupled amplifier ? What is the DC voltage at Q1 collector? And the voltage swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the overall circuit input goes high, Q1 will turn on pulling the base of Q3 low.  When the base of Q3 drops more than about 0.7 V below the emitter (positive voltage rail) Q3 will be begin to conduct between the emitter and collector.  This pulls the base of Q4 high, turning it on, pulling the output high.

When the overall circuit input goes low, Q1 will turn off leaving the base of Q3 high.  When the base of Q3 goes up to the rail, it stops conducting between the emitter and collector.  This allows the base of Q4 to go low, turning it off.  It also lets the base of Q5 go low, turning it on, and pulling the final output low.

Comment: amazing that was i was looking for

Comment: just one more thing about Q3. what is your opinion that they use an PNP instead of an NPN here? there was a huge discussion about that. thanks

Comment: The PNP type can pull the collector all the way up to the rail voltage.  An NPN could only pull it up to 0.7 V below the rail.  Of course the last stage uses and NPN at the positive, so the final output can never exceed Vrail - 0.7, but were Q3 an NPN, the final rail would be limited to Vrail - 1.4.

Comment: "NPN could only pull it up to 0.7 V below the rail" But I dont understand this. If Q3 were NPN and if it was ON, wouldn't its collector be all the way up to the rail voltage as well?

Comment: oh sorry, I think you meant in PNP case there is not 0.7 voltage drop Vbe. But in NPN case collector voltage will follow base voltage by minus 0.7. Did I understand you right?

Comment: Yup, you're right!  I mixed them up!

Answer (score 3):

It's just a common-emitter amplifier stage. Imagine it flipped around (NPN) with just R6 as the load (D1+D2 and the transistors just have a constant voltage drop of 2*Vbe to a first approximation.

In the actual circuit, when the base goes lower, the base current increases and the collector goes higher, so it inverts just as you'd expect of a common-emitter amplifier. DC feedback (and AC feedback) is provided for the circuit as a whole by R7 & R8, so that's where the bias is coming from.
[image]
This circuit can be analyzed as three blocks- input 'long-tailed pair' Q1/Q2, Q3 which amplifies the voltage appearing across the collector load of one of the transistors, and the output voltage followers Q4/Q5. The diodes are intended to reduce crossover distortion and bias Q4/Q5 locally so they conduct a bit. The circuit would still work without the diodes D1/D2 (replaced with a short) but would produce more distortion. R2/R2 provide input bias and R7/R8 determine overall feedback. C1 and C2 are coupling capacitors. Incidentally, as Olin mentions, I've found it's usually best to think of transistors as current-operated devices when analyzing bias and switching behavior, but as voltage-operated devices when analyzing small signal behavior. In this circuit you'd want to find out where the bias is so you know that the transistors are biased properly and not saturated, but to analyze the open-loop gain, for example, you'd need to use small signal analysis.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to notice is that the emitter voltage is fixed to the supply rail.  This means the base voltage will also be reasonably constant.  This transistor is being used as a current amplifier.

Keep in mind that since the impedances aren't infinite or zero, calling it a current amplifier is more to simplify our thought processes of how it works.  You could analyze it by considering the voltages instead, but that would be more complicated and yield less well to simplifying assumptions in this case.

We consider the output of Q3 to be a variable current source that is reasonably independent of its output voltage.  Much of this current will go thru R6.  Since the bottom of R6 is grounded, the voltage at the top of R6 will be a voltage proportional to the current produced by Q3.  Along the way a little of this current will be diverted to drive Q4, and a little current will be added due to driving Q5.  Considering the voltage at the top of R6 as being proportional to the current out of Q3 is therefore a approximation, but then again so is everything else.  In this case it's a valid enough approximation so we can not get swamped with details but still understand how the circuit works.

D1 and D2 act as fixed voltage drops at first approximation, intended to compenstate for the B-E voltage drops of Q4 and Q5.  Basically, the current out of Q3 controls the voltages of the bases of Q4 and Q5.  Q4 and Q5 are operated as *emitter followers*, which provide current gain at about unity voltage gain.  The point of the Q4,Q5 stage is to provide a lower impedance output to the voltage signal produced by R6.  Lower impedance at the same voltage implies higher current, which is why Q4,Q5 is a current amplifier.  In the special case of unity voltage gain, we sometimes use the term *buffer*.

The input to Q3 is also a current signal since the base is being held at a reasonably constant voltage.  Q1,Q2 form a *differential pair*, which takes the difference between two voltages, and in this case amplifies is.  You can think of the whole circuit a bit like a opamp.  The base of Q1 is the positive input, and the base of Q2 the negative input.  A fraction of the output is fed back into the negative input to set the gain of the overall amplifier.